# Scala Anorm - how use it properly

Tags: scala, anorm

Scala's play framework claims that Anorm, and writing your own SQL is better that ORM's. One of the reasons is that you anyway most often want only transfer data between database and frontend as json. However, most tutorials, and even Play documentation give examples of parsing sql's returned values into case classes, in order to parse it again into json. We still have an object relational mapping anyway, or am I missing a point?

In my database there exists a table with 33 columns. Declaring a case class takes me 33 lines, declaring a parser with ~ operator, takes another 33. Using case statement to create an Object, another 66! Seriously, what am I doing wrong? Is there any shortcut? In django the same thing takes only 33 lines.

Comment: You miss the real difference between Anorm&ORM:ORM generates queries dynamically,according mapping descriptors.With Anorm,you do the query,as you know the best your DB,and it provides only convenient results parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Anorm within a Play application, then the mapping into a Json object of your case class (assuming it has fairly normal apply and unapply functions defined for it, which most do) should be pretty much as simple as defining an implicit which uses the >2.10 macro based Json-inception methods...so all you actually need is a definition like this:

```
implicit val myCaseFormats = Json.format[MyCaseClass]
```

where 'MyCaseClass' is the name of your case type.  You could even bake this into the parser combinator you use for de-serialising row-sets back from the database...that would dramatically clean up your code and cut down the amount of code you have to write.

See here for details on the Json macros: 
 https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception

I use this quite extensively in a pretty large code-base and it does make things quite clean.

In terms of your parsers for Anorm, remember that you don't *have* to produce a case-class instance as a result of a parse...you can actually return anything you like, which could just be an indexed sequence of your column values (if you're using something like Shapeless to allow for mixed-type lists etc...) or some other structure.

You do hav macro support in Anorm as well so the the parsers for your case classes can be one liners like this:

```
import norm.{Macro, Rowset}

val parser = Macro.namedParser[MyCaseClass]
```

If you want to do something custom, (such as parse direct to JsValue) then you have the flexibility to just hand-craft a more crafty parser.

HTH

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks! However, in my database I have tables with columns number > 22, and since json macros uses apply + unapply functions on my case classes, I can not use the macro, nor can I use json play library...

Comment: You could however split the columns between two case classes (if that makes sense), utilise macros to parse them and then combine the two parsers using ~ or ~> to combine them into a single parser which returns either a tuple (pair of case class A and case class B) or even embeds them into a container case class?

Comment: For the JSON side of things you might be able to do something using JSON transformations - take a look at the documentation on the Play site - depends what you want to do with the resultant data structures...